# CodeRush Templates and Intellisense

Tags: devexpress, intellisense

I am creating custom code snippet templates using DevExpress' CodeRush.

Is there anyway for me to be able to see available Templates through Intellisense so I don't have to memorize the names of all of the templates that I want to create?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was I created visual studio snippets with the same name as the CodeRush templates in question.  This allowed me to have the intellisense popup when I started to type the name of the template (b/c Visual Studio thought I was using a snippet) and then I can just hit the hotkey to use the CodeRush template.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [CodeRush Training](http://www.skorkin.com/2010/08/coderush-training-window/) tool window for this purpose. Just dock it to the appropriate position (e.g. to the left side of the Visual Studio IDE) and see what code snippet templates it suggests. The window is context sensitive, so only appropriate code templates suggestions are made. I assume that after some time you will remember all useful templates you will work with.